# How to quckly search repeated values in pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a column from data frame: 900k rows. Structure of pandas Series:

`base['SampleID']` =

```
231233
124123
213h213
jkiu12341
213i12i24u
```

I have also a `listOfNames` contains 84k strings 
ex. `listOFNames =[jkiu12341,das2123,233213,321n3ju213]`

**What I need to do?**

I need to compare each value from the list to data series (`base['SampleID]'`) rows and check if it contains repetition.

If the script found the same value in Series, should save it (append) to another DataFrame, if not it should just pass.

**Problems:**

I need to use regex, coz sometimes in the list I would have for example `ff5434`when in Series: '00ff5434' - and it's should be read as repetition.

I wrote a function in python but it's horribly slow. Compared 900k rows take 35-40 min.

My code:

```
found = 0
notfound = 0

for i in range(len(listOfNames)):
    if len(base[base['SampleId'].str.contains(listOfNames[i], regex=False)]) > 0 :
        found += 1
    else:
        notfound+= 1
```

So it's very simple `for loop` scanning the whole Series. And it's not append founded rows to a data frame yet, just counts how many repeated I have.

**Expecting result:**

Dataframe with repetition. In the above example it will be: just dataframe or list contains `jkiu12341`.

Maybe someone knows native pandas function, or any other library helps do it faster and replace my for function?

Comment: please create a short [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to replicate your question.

Comment: This way you will catch false positives. is trailing 00 the only difference ? and regex = False show you DONT use regex ?

Comment: You can use set intersection to determine the common values, after you cleanup/normalize the data for leading or trailing 0's (and if there are other similar patterns in your data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to find the value in a list, you can do the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'base': ['231233', '124123', '213h213', 'jkiu12341', 
                             '213i12i24u'],})
listOFNames =['jkiu12341','das2123','233213','321n3ju213']
# Result as a list
output=list(df.base[df['base'].isin(listOFNames)])
print(output)
# Result as a DataFrame
df_result=pd.DataFrame(output,columns=['output'])
print(df_result)
```

Output:

```
['jkiu12341']

      output
0  jkiu12341
```

time that is needed to execute search operation:

```
%timeit output=list(df.base[df['base'].isin(listOFNames)])

585 µs ± 46.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank U that help me very much and I learned something new ! :)

Answer (score 1):

How about `where` from `pandas`? info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-where/). Or, also, `where` from `numpy`? info [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Without a  minimal, complete and verifiable example ([mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) as @anky_91 pointed out is difficult to do more.